# Split sorted list of integers by groups of consecutive integers

Tags: list-manipulation, programming

Im a trying to split a ***sorted*** 1D list of integers by sets of consecutives integers. The keywords in the question didn't trigger the answers I was looking for so I ask the question, no matter how trivial it looks like...

I just want for instance transform a list like:

```
   pts= {915, 916, 917, 1324, 1325, 1326, 2070, 2071, 2072, 2073, 2817, 2818, 2819, 2820, 3568, 3569, 3570}
```

Into a list like:

```
   {{915, 916, 917}, {1324, 1325, 1326}, {2070, 2071, 2072, 2073}, {2817,
   2818, 2819, 2820}, {3568, 3569, 3570}}
```

I tried **FindClusters[ ]** but could not tune the classification function fine enough and kept finding some cases where sets differing by a small difference where grouped together. I tried also similar global operators Gather[]but I always found some specific cases where sets were not correct.

So, swallowing my pride, I went to a procedural program:

```
clusterize[pts_] := Module[{j = 1, c = {}, b},
  While[j <= Length[pts],
    b = {pts[[j]]};
    Do[If[pts[[i + 1]] - pts[[i]] == 1, AppendTo[b, pts[[i + 1]]], 
     j = i; Break[]], {i, j, Length[pts] - 1}]; AppendTo[c, b]; 
   j = j + 1;]; Return[c]]
```

But this is not satisfactory, I keep finding idiotic cases like:

```
pts= {915, 916, 917, 1324, 1325, 1326, 2070, 2071, 2072, 2073, 2817, 2818,2819, 2820, 3568, 3569, 3570}
```

Gives:

```
In[27]:= clusterize[pts]

Out[27]= {{915, 916, 917}, {1324, 1325, 1326}, {2070, 2071, 2072, 
  2073}, {2817, 2818, 2819, 2820}, {3568, 3569, 3570}, {3569, 
  3570}, {3570}}
```

So can someone help me to find the bug in my procedural programming or much better a functionnal programming way to do the trick (or with patterns) ?

Comment: Can you explain what is wrong with Gather?  Split is older than Gather and what I show in my answer is exactly how we implemented Gather-like functionality before Gather was introduced.  If my answer works, so should Gather and vice versa ...

Comment: As for searching for duplicate posts: I don't use the search functionality within SE but rather just google for relevant posts. I found the above proposed duplicate by googling "mathematica stack exchange split list by consecutive integers".

Comment: Just a note, if you tried something, and it didn't work on all lists, use a list as example in which it *doesn't* work, because in the example list `FindClusters[]` does work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about [`Split`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Split.html)?

```
Split[Sort[pts], Abs[#1 - #2] <= 1 &]
```

I haven't looked at performance though.

Comment: In the OP the numbers are already sorted. However, since you additionally included  `Sort` in your solution I thought of being picky and trying to find a case where it does not work. For `pts = {1, 2, 4, 2, 3, 3, 3}` we get `{{1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4}}` although I would expect `{{1, 2}, {4}, {2, 3, 3, 3}}`.

Comment: @Szabolcs: thanks this is exactly what I wanted. It works well!I tried also the same syntax with Gather and it returns only pairs. And GatherBy with the same syntax and function return errors

Answer (score 2):

(Edited to employ `Differences`)

@Szabolcs's aswer is pretty much perfect, but let my add my procedural solution:

```
clusterize[pts_] := Module[{diffs, pos},
  diffs = Differences[pts];
  pos = Append[Prepend[Flatten@Position[diffs, x_ /; x > 1] + 1, 1], Length@pts + 1];
  Table[
   Table[pts[[i]], {i, pos[[j]], pos[[j + 1]] - 1}]
   , {j, 1, Length@pos - 1}]
  ]
```

Let's append one more value to the initial list to show that `clusterize` is functional:

```
pts = {915, 916, 917, 1324, 1325, 1326, 2070, 2071, 2072, 2073, 2817, 2818, 2819, 2820, 3568, 3569, 3570, 4000};
```

Thence

```
clusterize[pts]
```

gives

> {{915, 916, 917}, {1324, 1325, 1326}, {2070, 2071, 2072, 2073}, {2817,
>      2818, 2819, 2820}, {3568, 3569, 3570}, {4000}}

If you have repeating values, e.g. `pts={...,4000,4000}`, both @Szabolcs's and my answer will give `{...,{4000,4000}}`. If you don't want them in the output, then maybe use `Map[DeleteDuplicates, clusterize[pts]]`.

---

**EDIT: Machine Learning**

It might appear that `FindClusters` should be a natural choice for such a problem:

```
FindClusters[pts]
```

> {{915, 916, 917, 1324, 1325, 1326, 2070, 2071, 2072, 2073, 2817, 2818,
>      2819, 2820, 3568, 3569, 3570, 4000}}

but it fails. Maybe with some `DistanceFunction`:

```
FindClusters[pts, DistanceFunction -> ManhattanDistance]
```

> {{915, 916, 917}, {1324, 1325, 1326}, {2070, 2071, 2072, 2073}, {2817,
>      2818, 2819, 2820}, {3568, 3569, 3570, 4000}}

Better, but `4000` should be in a separate group (other `DistanceFunction`s don't work either). Even specifying the number of clusters explicitly fails:

```
FindClusters[pts, 6]
```

> {{915, 916, 917}, {1324, 1325, 1326}, {2070, 2071}, {2072, 
>     2073}, {2817, 2818, 2819, 2820}, {3568, 3569, 3570, 4000}}

(Note: the above two methods happen to work when `4000` is deleted from `pts`.)

So maybe some classification?

```
c = ClusterClassify[pts]
```

> Method: DBSCAN
>
> Number of classes: 6

Looks promising;

```
GatherBy[pts, c]
```

> {{915, 916, 917}, {1324, 1325, 1326}, {2070, 2071, 2072, 2073}, {2817,
>      2818, 2819, 2820}, {3568, 3569, 3570}, {4000}}

Correct! Is it general enough?

```
pts2 = {1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 10, 11, 13};
c = ClusterClassify[pts2]
GatherBy[pts2, c]
```

> {{1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 10, 11, 13}}

It fails miserably. But wait, in the case of `pts` Method: DBSCAN was used automatically. Maybe:

```
c = ClusterClassify[pts2, Method -> "DBSCAN"]
GatherBy[pts2, c]
```

> {{1, 2, 3}, {5, 6}, {8}, {10, 11}, {13}}

Correct! Works also for `{1, 2, 4, 5}`, `{1, 3, 4, 5}`, `{1, 2, 3, 5}`, `{1, 2, 5}` and `{1, 4, 5}`. Unfortunately, it fails for `{1, 3, 5}` or `{1, 2, 4}`. **Nevertheless**, it seems to work for a number of situations.

Comment: Some tips: `Differences` is useful.  To exact a range, consider `Part` and `Span`, as in `array[[i;;j]]`.

Comment: @corey979: thanks for taking the time to do this, It seems to work well, I will test  it further with new data. I am personnaly very rusted in procedural programming!...

Comment: ChristianNéel Thanks, but @Szabolcs answer is much better; I'd recommend to stick to that one and treat mine maybe as a reference for future issues.